# JDBC PreparedStatement.executeBatch does not update values in database and no error

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am trying to do update sybase db using JDBC `addBatch` `executeBatch`. I am creating table at run time and inserting values in jdbc batch. I am reading values from comma separated file in the following format

```
1,ABC,DEF
2,GHI,KJL

create query is CREATE TABLE School(schoolid int,schoolname varchar ,schooltype varchar )
insert query INSERT INTO School(schoolid,schoolname,schooltype) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

What is happening is I am getting no error code executes successfully but there is not values in the end database. Table is empty. I am also using `dbConn.commit()` but still empty table. Please guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're calling `addBatch();` before all of the necessary values are set!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your batches are smaller than `batchSize` which means you'll never reach a line with `pstmt.executeBatch();`, since `++count % batchSize == 0` never evaluates to true.

You can easily fix that by adding a line with `pstmt.executeBatch();` right after closing the `while` loop. That way, any remaining rows that didn't cause the batch to be executed and a new batch to be created will be executed at the end.

Comment: If there are multiple rows in CSV file.. the if condition should eventually become true.. from the post it looks like CSV has multiple lines.

Comment: "eventually become true"... unless there are less rows than `batchSize`; in that case the `if`-statement **never** becomes true, and hence the batch is never executed.

Comment: @sanbhat: from the post it looks like the csv has 2 lines, and `batchSize` is 3...

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i thought if condition is within for loop. But it is not. actually one more } is missing which is confusing me

Comment: @sanbhat: the `if` statement is within the loop... The code formatting is horrible, though.

Comment: so `batchSize=3` and `colArray.length` will be `6 `(`2` rows each row has `3` tokens) after `2` iteratiions.. so wouldn't the `if `condition become true?

Comment: @sanbhat: `colArray.length` will be `3` for each row. It doesn't grow.

Comment: but the `count` will grow rite? so in the 2nd iteration of `while` loop `count` will be 6 ? and `6%3` will be 0. By `colArray.length` i meant to say `count`

Comment: @sanbhat: No, `count` is reset to 0 on every iteration of the `while` loop.